# Kotlin can't get purchaseId with rxBilling

Tags: android, kotlin

I'am trying to use rxBilling for in app purchases on my android app. library found here : https://github.com/betterme-dev/RxBilling

i manage to implemente it like this :

```
private fun launchBilling(subscription: Boolean) {
        val sku = "com.app.subscription"

        disposable.add(rxBilling.launchFlow(
            this, BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSku(sku)
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                .build()
        )
            .subscribe({

            }, {
                it.message?.let { msg -> unknownError(0, msg) }
            })
        )
    }`
```

This is working perfectly, i pushed my app in internal test and i tried to subscribe, it's worked and i verified in my google play console that my subscription was taken into account.
The problem is that i want to get information of the purchase like date and transaction id. So i followed the guideline and implemented a disposable in the on start method :

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        println("onstrat")
        disposable.add(
            rxBilling.observeUpdates()
                .subscribe({
                    println("here")
                    it.purchases.forEach { item ->
                        println("rxbillingstart")
                        println(item.toString())
                        println(item)
                        println(item.sku)
                        purchase(item)
                    }

                }, {
                    togglePurchaseProgress(false)
                    it.message?.let { msg -> unknownError(0, msg) }
                })
        )
    }
```

And for the implementation of the rxbilling and disposable in the on create method :

```
    private lateinit var rxBilling: RxBilling
    private lateinit var rxBillingFlow: RxBillingFlow
    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    rxBilling = RxBillingImpl(BillingClientFactory(applicationContext))
    rxBillingFlow = RxBillingFlow(applicationContext, BillingServiceFactory(this))
    lifecycle.addObserver(BillingConnectionManager(rxBilling))
    lifecycle.addObserver(BillingConnectionManager(rxBillingFlow))
```

The purchase methode is juste here to print item.orderId date ... but it's never called. Also my first print "onstrat" in the onStart method is called but all other print in the observable.subscribe are never called. Do I miss something? i don't get why i can't get subsciption informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that RxBilling is no longer maintained, so i used standard android billing client found here : https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate .But don't forget to add to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Then implemente those interface in your activity : `PurchasesUpdatedListener, SkuDetailsResponseListener` and set up the billing client variable : `private lateinit var billingClient : BillingClient` . Also it was unclear to me at first but sku is the product id you set up on googleplay console.

```
private fun buy(){

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()

        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
                    skuList.add("premium_upgrade")
                    skuList.add("com.yourappname.subscription")
                    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)

                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), this@DetailsActivity)

                }
            }
            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        })
    }
```

Set up the skudetails you are searching for like this, then get the response here :

```
 override fun onSkuDetailsResponse(responseCode: BillingResult, skuDetailsList: MutableList<SkuDetails>?) {
       
        if (responseCode.responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            Log.w("LOG_TAG", "SkuDetails query failed with response: $responseCode")
        } else {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "SkuDetails query responded with success. List: $skuDetailsList")

            if (skuDetailsList != null) {
                for (skuDetails in skuDetailsList) {
                    var sku = skuDetails.getSku ()
                    var price = skuDetails.getPrice ()

                    var params = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                        .build();

                    if (sku == "com.yourappname.subscription") {
                        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, params);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This mean that if i found the right sku i lauchBillingflow -> i start the process of paying. Then you get the result on the payement here :

```
override fun onPurchasesUpdated(billingResult: BillingResult, purchases: MutableList<Purchase>?) {
    
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
            for (purchase in purchases) {
                purchase(1, purchase)
            }
        } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
        } else {
            // Handle any other error codes.
        }
    }
```

You can here get the result on your purchase such as purchaseTime, orderId, purchaseToken, and then my function purchase send the purchaseToken to an internal server to verify the transaction.

Hope it's will help some of you.